# quadratic Diophantine system of equations: $A=b^2-ac$,$B=ad-bc$,$C=c^2-bd$.

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

Given integers $A$, $B$, $C$, I would like to solve the following system of quadratic equations for integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
A &= b^2 - ac, \\
B &= ad - bc, \\
C &= c^2 - bd. \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The equations are relating a binary cubic form $ax^3 + 3bx^2y + 3cxy^2 + dy^3$, to one of its 'covariants' ([web1](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/math/invar.html), [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_of_a_binary_form)), a binary quadratic form $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2$.  As you can see, it is easy to start from the cubic form and get the binary form, but it is not clear to me how to do the opposite.

Playing with this, I found that there are some nice 'linear' equations hidden in there
$$
\begin{aligned}
c A + b B + a C &= c (b^2 - ac) + b (ad - bc) + a (c^2 - bd) = 0, \\
d A + c B + b C &= d (b^2 - ac) + c (ad - bc) + b (c^2 - bd) = 0. \\
\end{aligned}
$$

So I'm hoping there is some "nice" way to solve this with linear tools (extended Euclidean algorithm).

However there are also some rearrangements that isolate two of the variables in a quadratic equation
$$
\begin{aligned}
b^2 A + ab B + a^2 C &= b^2 (b^2 - ac) + ab (ad - bc) + a^2 (c^2 - bd) \\
 &= b^2 (b^2 - ac) - ab(bc) + a^2 (c^2) \\
 &= (b^2 - ac)^2 \\
 &= A^2 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Also, $AC=c^2A+bcB+b^2C, C^2=d^2A+cdB+c^2C.$

Comment: might have an answer in https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cubic_Fields_with_Geometry/Q8t2DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover  as the author asked pretty much the same question on MO

Comment: @WillJagy Can you please link to the question on MO?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149612/is-eisensteins-map-from-binary-cubic-forms-really-injective-when-delta-0

Answer (score 1):

One infinite family of  these binary quadratic forms is $$\langle U,  V, U^2 \rangle$$  which arises from
$$  a = 1,  b = 0,  c = -U,  d = V $$

We see that this has order (dividing) three in the class group because Dirichlet's method of composition shows
$$\langle U,  V, U^2 \rangle^3    \equiv \langle U^3,  V, 1 \rangle$$
which is the identity form.

One must adjust the middle coefficient to have this work out;

This is in chapter XII, pages 253-258 in **Volume 3** of Dickson, *History of the Theory of Numbers*. He says Eisenstein described the invariants and covariants in 1844.

Apparently Pepin (1883)  showed surjectivity   for this when the discriminant of the quadratic form is $-4p$  and $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ is prime. I can't tell (yet) whether Eisensteins's map is surjective in general.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "showed surjectivity for **this**"?  Is the claim that for every binary quadratic form and binary cubic form with the required relationship, the cubic form is SL(2,Z) equivalent to one with a=1,b=0, when the discriminant of the quadratic form is -4p and p = 3 (mod 4) is prime?  In such a case I can see that we must have gcd(A,B)=gcd(A,a)=gcd(a,b)=1. However I see no reason there should always be a solution with a=1, b=0. So maybe I am misunderstanding the claim here.

Comment: @Qvinton  I've requested Eisenstein's collected works. The clearest staement    until then is a recent article by Hoffman and Morales  https://www.math.lsu.edu/~morales/assets/files/Hoffman-Morales2000_Binary_cubic_forms.pdf

Comment: Looks like in the case of p = 3 (mod 8), there will always be a non-identity form that satisfied this as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563833/relation-of-quadratic-forms-with-discriminant-p-prime-and-4p